# htmlagilitypack slow at first run

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, html-agility-pack

For first run it takes more than 15 seconds... after first run it takes less than 1 sec... how I can fix it???

```
System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();   

sw.Start();
siteKeyword = tbSearch.Text;
web.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
doc = web.Load(siteSearch + siteKeyword);
HtmlNodeCollection items = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='cls1']");

int i = 0;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    lbResults.Items.Add(item.SelectSingleNode("h2/a").InnerText);
    resultsHREF.Add(item.SelectSingleNode("h2/a").Attributes["href"].Value);
    i++;
}
sw.Stop();
MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("00:00:000"));
sw.Reset();
```

Comment: We need more context.  What do you mean by "first run"? The first run after building the code? The first time you call this function within your code? The first time you run it on a new machine?  Also, are you running this from a WinForm app? A WPF app? A website?

Comment: I running it from WinForm... this code above is button called search... When the form load and i write keyword and pressing that button it takes 15 seconds to do the job, after that if i click it again (for same keyword or other) it takes 1 second... if i restart the program it takes again 15 second for first click and 1 second for next clicks

Comment: Could this be a bad dns-resolving? Or tcp connectivity issues? Are you loading a local or a remote document?

Comment: remote... i don't have any network issue.. its same on my friends computer... I had same problem with webclient and i solved it by writing `webclient.Proxy = null;` without that it was needed 20 second after i put this line it was needed 2 sec.... there should be a similar trick for this

Comment: It could be caching the page the first time you download it.  Put your stopwatch around the `web.Load(siteSearch + siteKeyword);` call, and see if that's the function which takes much longer the first time.

Comment: yes that function takes so much time... What I can do?

Comment: @Loclip - Not much.  It takes a while because it has to go load that webpage, then parse it.